# Using SUM on FLOAT data

Tags: mysql

One table:
items(id, price)

Has one row:
id: 1, price: 565.8

`SELECT price FROM items` gives `565.8`
`SELECT SUM(price) FROM items` gives `565.799987792969` instead of `565.8` which I'd expect.

Where does the `565.799987792969` come from?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure what version you are using, but it sounds like [this link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1961) describes what you are experiencing.

From the link:

```
mysql> select * from aaa;
+----+------------+------+
| id | month_year | cost |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 | 2002-05-01 | 0.01 |
|  2 | 2002-06-01 | 1.65 |
|  3 | 2002-07-01 | 0.01 |
|  4 | 2002-01-01 | 0.01 |
+----+------------+------+

mysql> select id, sum(cost) from aaa group by id;
+----+---------------------+
| id | sum(cost)           |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 0.00999999977648258 |
|  2 |    1.64999997615814 |
|  3 | 0.00999999977648258 |
|  4 | 0.00999999977648258 |
+----+---------------------+

The SUM function changes 0.01 to 0.00999999977648258.
```

Floating point numbers are stored as approximate values; if you are storing a price, you are better off using a decimal datatype which stores precise values.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) or [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(price), 2) FROM items;
```

Alternatively you can specify precision when defining a column, e.g. `FLOAT(5,2)`.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful but it doesn't answer the question.