# Incorrect decimals appearing in SUM MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum

I have the following SQL query.

```
SELECT SUM(final_insurance_total) as total
FROM `leads`
GROUP BY leads.status
```

I have a single row of data in the lead table with a value for final_insurance_total of 458796. The data type for final_insurance_total is `float`.

For some reason, MySQL is summing a single row as "458796.375".

If I change the query to

```
SELECT (final_insurance_total) as total
FROM `leads`
GROUP BY leads.status
```

the correct value is returned. What in the world is going on?

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1961

Comment: Simular issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907021/using-sum-on-float-data

Comment: Here is a good explanation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: If you can avoid using `FLOAT`, use a fixed-place [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html) type instead.

Comment: This is not a trivial floating-point error issue as referenced by previous links. A small interger such as 458796 should be represented without loss of precision. I'm curious to know what your platform is, perhaps you are on an exotic system that does not use the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: @MarcusAdams maybe summing the single row would be better?  I mean it makes sense in this context seeing as he only has the one row in the table.

Comment: Switch to MariaDB: MySQL Errors are fixed very slow. The problem you see is a clear one, there are other failure scenarios which can really ruin your day like incorrect results from views with limit used in joins (Select on the view gives list A, use in a join of the given view gives list B).

Answer (score 4):

The `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` types in MySQL (as well as in other databases and programming language runtimes) are represented in a special way, which leads to the values stored being approximations, not exact values. See [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/floating-point-types.html), as well as [general information on floating-point arithmetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

In order to store and operate with exact values, use the type `DECIMAL` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).

**EDIT:** I have run some tests, and while floating-point precision errors are quite common, this particular one looks to be specific to the implementation of `SUM()` in MySQL. In other words, it is a bug that has been there for a long time. In any case, you should use `DECIMAL` as your field type.

Answer (score 1):

`FLOAT` does not guarantee precision where any calculation is made. If you use a simple `SELECT`, no calculation is made, so you get the original value. But if you use `SUM()`, even with one row, at least one addition is executed (`0 + current_value`).

Do you really need `FLOAT`? For example, if you have 2 decimal digits, you could use INT and multiply all values by 100 before all `INSERT`s. When `SELECT`ing results, you will divide by 100.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not a sysadmin and cannot change the datatype of the field such as FLOAT, the user can use CAST to produce the desired output.