# MySQL SUM returning unnecessary decimals

Tags: php, mysql

I have single record on a table. So on MySQL when

```
 select myamount from table 1  -- returns amount 420.67
```

But when i do MySQL as

```
 select sum(myamount) from table 1 -- returns amount 420.8699951171875
```

should n't it return same amount 420.67 since I have only one record? and how to get amount 420.67 if SUM used.

Any help is appreciated and yes myamount datatype is float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SUM on FLOAT data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907021/using-sum-on-float-data)

Answer (score 1):

Float variables are stored in "scientific notation" (the 2,4E+04 format, which is the same as 2,4*10^4). But to make it even worse, it is also stored in binary. When calculating things with numbers stored as float, you may get a bit strange results because of this.

[This video by](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) Computerphile describes the problem very nicely.