# MySQL SUM function for summing all the money

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I have a need to sum all of the money from the underlying DB.

I have 2 options to do that.

1. Use the SQL SUM() function to sum it up or
2. Get the list of all the money and sum in memory.

I think it would be better to use the first option considering better performance but **I want to know if SUM function can be safely used to sum the monetary amount without loosing the precision**.

If it were the 2nd option I would have used Java's BigDecimal which is used to represent money.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe SUM behavior is based on datatype of values being summed.

Comment: Why not safely? Many banking systems are using it, and are still working...

Comment: when you doing the select, the table will be locked for insert/update that means "SAFE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `DECIMAL(m, 2)` (assuming 2 decimal places for *your* currency), MySQL's `SUM()` will be exact and faster than fetching all the rows, shoveling them into the client, then doing the equivalent arithmetic with a similar library.

`AVG` has precision issues in *any* situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the datatype you are using.
if you're using floats, there is some precision lost in mysql (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907021/using-sum-on-float-data) and [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1961)), if you are using decimals, then you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

> Returns the summation of all expression values in the most precise expression data type.

SUM will not lose precision any more than your local processor would, you are safe to use it.

Edit:

I mistakenly posted some T-SQL docs, here are the mySQL docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

> The SUM() and AVG() functions return a DECIMAL value for exact-value arguments (integer or DECIMAL), and a DOUBLE value for approximate-value arguments (FLOAT or DOUBLE).

So identically to T-SQL, it will choose the most precise data type.

Comment: That's a different database entirely.

Comment: It would be more appreciated if you can provide documentation of MySQL instead of T-SQL.